# Blazor WASM: Get error from Http.ReadFromJsonAsync<string>: "The JSON value could not be converted to System.String."

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly, .net-5

I am using a Blazor WASM project with Hosted ASP.NET Core 5 WebAPI. When I try to deserialize the return of a method it brings this error.

I have this ApiController that receives my Post

```cs
public ActionResult SendReports( [FromBody] Invoices listInvoices) 
{
    //Do Something
    if (status == Ok) 
    {
        return Ok();
    } 
    else 
    {
        return BadRequest(new ResponseMessage { Descriptcion = "Something went wrong." });
    }
}
```

I send from my Blazor razor pages using:

```cs
var response = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync($"Invoices/SendReports?SendReports={listInvoices}", listInvoices);
```

I check the response status to deserialize:

```cs
if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
    { // Algun error del bloque trycatch
        var error = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<string>();
                
        NotificationComponent.Show(Notificacion.NotificacionError("error", $"¡ Error, {error} !"));
   }
   else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
   { // Algun error del bloque trycatch
       var error = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<string>();

       NotificationComponent.Show(Notificacion.NotificacionError("error", $"¡ Error, {error} !"));
   }
}
```

The class of Invoices:

```cs
public class listInvoices
{
    public List<Invoices> Invoices { get; set; }
    public List<ProductoDto> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Class of ResponseMessage:

```cs
public class ResponseMessage 
{
    public string Descriptcion { get; set; }
}
```

The error occurs when it tries to deserialize from `response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<string>();`.
The Response from the Controller is this:

> {"descriptcion":"Something went wrong"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your API controller, it returns a `ResponseMessage` object.

```cs
return BadRequest(new ResponseMessage { Descriptcion = "Something went wrong." });
```

You should deserialize the `response.Content` as `ResponseMessage` type but not as `string` type.

```cs
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
{
    var response = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ResponseMessage>();

    NotificationComponent.Show(Notificacion.NotificacionError("error", $"¡ Error, {response.Descriptcion} !"));
}
```

Comment: I do that and I get this error message:
'e' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0

Comment: If you debug `response.Content`, what value is shown?

Comment: I can't debug response.Content for some VS doesn't catch the breakpoint on .NET 5 and is not possible to migrate to .NET 6, supposedly an issue on this version.

Thanks, you were right, I missed response.Description 
I bashed my head so much that should stop, get a wider view, rest, my cold head, and come again.

Comment: No worries. Glad to see that my answer helps.